# Why Date object one day behind only on the server side but not on the localhost in javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, date, datetime, hosting

The following code appends 00 hrs, mts and sec on the date

```
let setStartSTime = new Date(my_date);
setStartSTime = setStartSTime.getFullYear() + "-"
              + (setStartSTime.getMonth()+1) + "-"
              + setStartSTime.getDate()+" "
              + 00 + ":"+ 00 + ":"+ 00;
    console.log(setStartSTime + 'setStartSTime');
```

||ly, The following code appends 23 hrs, 59 mts and 59 sec on the date

```
let endStartSTime = new Date(my_date);
    endStartSTime = endStartSTime.getFullYear() + "-"
                  + (endStartSTime.getMonth()+1) + "-"
                  + endStartSTime.getDate()+" "
                  + 23 + ":"+ 59 + ":"+ 59;
```

The server hosted in US Amazon Server. That's why Date object takes one day behind the date that I have passing

If I pass 25th, then it will take 24, for 24, it is 23rd and son

How can I override this thing ?
I am using nodejs for server side 
I hope I am able to explain it.

Comment: What is the value of *my_date*? If it's an ISO 8601 date only format like "2017-05-22" then it should be parsed as UTC on any system compliant with ECMAScript 2015 or later. Methods like *getFullYear* return local values that are adjusted by the host timezone offset, so different timezone offsets mean you get different local times.

Comment: 2017-05-17 (yyyy-MM-dd)

Answer (score 0):

**Explanation**

It is because of the timeZone on server we have default UTC time (We can set default timeZone of our choice as well). So basically as you are from India your timeZone is 5:30 hr(330 minutes) ahead of UTC that's why you might be getting the issue if your server is set to US time zone then you might be about 11-12 hours behind India time.

**Solution**

You can check you server time (most probably it should be UTC) then you can get timeZone from client side and create your date accordingly so that you can maintain universal timing not country or region specific.

Comment: "*It is because of the timeZone on server we have default UTC time*" how do you know that?

Comment: [check this amazone doc](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/set-time.html) Amazon Linux instances are set to the UTC (Coordinated Universal Time) time zone by default, but you may wish to change the time on an instance to the local time or to another time zone in your network.